# Fusion will not boot Win7 after ubuntu install

Tags: vmware-fusion

I can boot Win 7 and Ubuntu 9.10 boot fine natively.

When I try to boot win7 in Fusion I get this:
GRUB loading. error: unknown filesystem, grup rescue>

After installing ubuntu 9.10 I followed this instructions on here and moved grub to the ubuntu partition.
which allowed ubuntu to load, but not win 7.

i used the win 7 dvd to do a boot record repair on the drive, but still win 7 will not load in Fusion 3.01

to Chopper3:

i am trying to boot from 2 different VMs.
i used the these commands to modify the 2 VMs.
./vmware-rawdiskCreator create /dev/disk1 2 "/temp.vmwarevm/ubuntu" ide
./vmware-rawdiskCreator create /dev/disk1 1 "/temp.vmwarevm/windows7" ide

I moved the *. vmdk files into their respective VMs.

so the win7 VM is pointing to partition 1 and the ubuntu VM is pointing to partition 2 of disk1.

launching the ubuntu VM works fine.
launching the win7 VM i get the grub error.

One more edit:

sorry for not making it clearer.

I am using 2 VMs. i am not trying to boot from that same vmdk files.

I am trying to boot 2 different virtual machines to 2 different boot camp partitions.
One VM boots the ubuntu boot camp partition. it works after following the directions posted in another post.

And one VM that boots the Windows 7 boot camp partition. gives me the grub error i posted earlier.

anyone have any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to get W7 and Ubuntu to boot from within the same Fusion VM, it's not clear?

If so, why? You could just have two VMs, one for each OS.

If not please clarify.

edit - thanks for the information, that said why on earth are you trying to boot two different OS VMs from the same vmdk file/s? or are you trying to do this from your bootcamp partition? if the former just use two separate vmdks and if the latter, well that isn't supported. If I've misread this again then please try to spell out exactly what you're trying to achieve please.

edit2 - I'm aware that some have managed to get Parallels to do what you're after but I can't seem to find any help on getting Fusion to do the same, do you HAVE to have all three OS's in physical partitions?

Comment: I've added some more information.